# Update content of p:dialog when we have changes in managed bean

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have an array list  to show in a p:dialog and this list was changed  when i click on command Button. Then I want to know how i can show the content of list for each change during excution of method in managed bean??

Synchronization between the iterative process in the managed bean and (DataList/progressbar) in a DialogBox.

DIALOG:

```
    <h:body><h:define name="dialogBox"><p:dialog id="genDialog" header="Opération de génération"  modal="true"  widgetVar="dlg1">  
              <h:outputText value="le traitement de la génération est en cours..." /> 
              <p:dataList id="sitesDataList" value="#{generationBean.generatedSites}"    var="siteStatus" itemType="square" >

                    #{siteStatus.site} ---------------> #{siteStatus.status}

              </p:dataList>

            </p:dialog>
</h:define >
</h:body>
```

CommandButton:

```
   `<h:form  id="form1" > <h:panelGrid  columns="2" id="panButton">` <p:commandButton  id="genbutton" style="margin-left: 930px"  value="#{generationBean.labelBoutonGen}"   immediate="true"  global="false" onstart="dlg1.show()"
                                          actionListener="#{generationBean.genererDPT}"   rendered="#{ generationBean.selectedRegion ne 'choix'}"  update="sitesDataList">

 </h:panelGrid  > </h:form>`
```

I'm running primefaces 3.5 in glassfish server

Answer (score 1):

Add `update="sitesDataList"` to your command button. If the command button and the data list are not in the same naming container, then you need to provide the full path to the datalist, something like `update=":myFormId:level1ContainerId:level2ContainerId:etc:sitesDatalist"`. Without seeing the complete code, I cannot give you an exact answer.

Comment: it doesn't refresh the list "sitesDataList"

Comment: Then you need to provide the code for the button and all the naming containers that nest both the button and the datalist.

Comment: You still didn't include the containing tags, naming containers being important.

Comment: Need to know the enclosing tags of the dialog - the full path from the root of the UI tree to the datalist, ok?

Comment: <h:body><h:define name="dialogBox"><p:dialog id="genDialog">

Comment: on a side note, how do you expect to update a modal dialog from a button that's not itself inside the dialog? you wouldn't be able to click it

Comment: Well i try to synchronize between iterative process in my Managed Bean and  a  dataList/progress Bar in a dialogBox

Comment: To do this i make a list between them.When a list change the component in dialogBox must be updated

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37268/discussion-between-khalid-lblid-and-rdcrng)